# Polynomial whose n no. of integrals are zero

Tags: algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

Is it true that, say $y(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $\le$ n, such that $\int^1_0 x^i y(x) dx = 0$ for $0 \le i \le n$ then y(x) is zero polynomial ? Prove or disprove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by linearity, you get that $\int_0^1 y^2(x)dx = 0$. Since $y^2$ is continuous and non-negative, you get that $y^2 = 0$ on $[0,1]$.

Since a non-zero polynomial can have only finitely many zeroes, you are done.

Comment: Yeah. That's nice. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Here's a start for you.

Consider $n=1$. Let $y(x) = ax + b$.

The conditions tell us that $\int_0^1 ax + b \, dx = 0, \int_0^1 ax^2 + bx \, dx = 0 $.

This is equivalent to $\frac{a}{2} + b = 0, \frac{a}{3} + \frac{b}{2} = 0 $.

This is a **2-variable, 2-equation system of linear equations**, and has a unique solution $a=0, b = 0$.

How do we generalize this to larger $n$?